# Sharepoint 2013 Copy site collection and change ID

Tags: sharepoint, copy, sharepoint-2013, sitecollection

i copy my site collection:

```
Copy-SPSite http://site/oldsite -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content -TargetUrl http://site/newsite
```

that's ok, but i need that the new site collection will have other id,  i want edit it to create other site with similar funtionalities.

Comment: Copy-SPSite will make sure new site will have different id.

Comment: Would there be any problem with the old site  if I modified the new site? @Vaibhav

Comment: In copy-spsite, we can mention destination content database. Hence new copy has no link with old copy.